# Progress bar (circle) setVisibility() doesn't exist anymore? (Android Java)

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, progress-bar

I want to turn my progress bar / circle invisible when the images are loaded on the page, but the setVisibilty() doesn't exist anymore. What is the subistute, because I couldn't find anything on the internet.

I wanted to call it after the setAdapter().

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notes_fragment, container, false);
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav = view.findViewById(R.id.bottomAppBar);
    MaterialToolbar topAppBar = view.findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
    bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.notes);
    mProgressCircle = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progress_circle);

    imageList = new ArrayList<>();

    currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    mUserRef = storage.getReference().child(currentUser.getEmail());
    gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridview);
    mUserRef.listAll().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<ListResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ListResult listResult) {
            for(StorageReference file:listResult.getItems()){
                Log.w(TAG, file.toString());
                file.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        imageList.add(uri.toString());
                        Log.w(TAG,"URI: " + uri.toString());
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                        adpter = new GridAdapter(getActivity(), imageList);
                        gridView.setAdapter(adpter);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

```
        android:id="@+id/progress_circle"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="78dp"
        android:layout_height="83dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
```

Comment: There has never been a `setInvisibility()` method on `ProgressBar`. Perhaps you are thinking of `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`.

Comment: Sorry a minor spelling mistake